# Use column value in other select

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select every category with a count of each product in this category and in each subcategory it is in.

This SQL QUERY returns the count of the products that a category with id `X` has, having in account its subcategory products.

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM productos
INNER JOIN categorias
ON categorias.id = productos.categoria_id
WHERE productos.categoria_id IN (select  id
        FROM    (SELECT * FROM categorias
                 ORDER BY parent, id) products_sorted,
                (SELECT @pv := X) initialisation
        WHERE   find_in_set(parent, @pv)
        AND     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
        OR      id = @pv)
        AND productos.active IS TRUE AND categorias.active IS TRUE
ORDER BY categorias.pos) as productos
```

Now I'm trying to get every category I have with the count of their products and this is my SQL, but it says unknown table `cats` in field list. I tried without alias as well. I suppose I can't use it inside the second select. So, how should I do it?

```
SELECT
    cats.*,
    (SELECT
        count(*)
    FROM productos
    INNER JOIN categorias
    ON categorias.id = productos.categoria_id
    WHERE productos.categoria_id IN (select  id
            FROM    (SELECT * FROM categorias
                     ORDER BY parent, id) products_sorted,
                    (SELECT @pv := cats.id) initialisation
            WHERE   find_in_set(parent, @pv)
            AND     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
            OR      id = @pv)
            AND productos.active IS TRUE AND categorias.active IS TRUE
    ORDER BY categorias.pos) as productos
FROM categorias AS cats ORDER BY cats.parent, cats.pos
```

Tables

```
+----------------------+
| Catrgorias           |
+----------------------+
| id (int 11)          |
+----------------------+
| nombre (varchar 255) |
+----------------------+
| parent (int 11)      |
+----------------------+
| active (tinyint 11)  |
+----------------------+
| pos (int 11)         |
+----------------------+
+----+------------+--------+
| id | nombre     | parent |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | Cat1       | NULL   |
+----+------------+--------+
| 2  | Cat2.      | NULL   |
+----+------------+--------+
| 3  | SubCat1    | 1      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 4  | SubCat2    | 2      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 5  | SubSubCat1 | 3      |
+----+------------+--------+


+-----------------------+
| Productos             |
+-----------------------+
| id (int 11)           |
+-----------------------+
| name (varchar 255)    |
+-----------------------+
| description (text)    |
+-----------------------+
| image (varchar 255)   |
+-----------------------+
| price (decimal 11,2)  |
+-----------------------+
| categoria_id (int 11) |
+-----------------------+
| pos (int 11)          |
+-----------------------+
| active (tinyint 11)   |
+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In the error message is there the line infected? In my opinion the problem is

```
(SELECT @pv := cats.id)
```

that I would change in

```
(SELECT @pv := id FROM CATEGORIAS)
```

I don't know if it is the solution for you, but I can't see other structural problems in your query.

To obtain the same result I'write something like that, check if it works (are you sure of the numbers you wrote in the comment?)

```
SELECT ID, SUM(N) FROM
#COLL DIRETTI
((SELECT A.ID AS ID, COUNT(*) AS N
FROM CATEGORIAS A
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTOS B
ON A.ID = B.CATEGORIA_ID
WHERE A.ACTIVE IS TRUE AND B.ACTIVE IS TRUE
GROUP BY A.ID)
UNION ALL
#PRIMA GENERAZIONE
(SELECT C.PARENT AS ID, D.N AS N
FROM CATEGORIAS C
LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.ID, COUNT(*) AS N
FROM CATEGORIAS A
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTOS B
ON A.ID = B.CATEGORIA_ID
WHERE A.ACTIVE IS TRUE AND B.ACTIVE IS TRUE
GROUP BY A.ID) D
ON C.ID = D.ID
WHERE C.PARENT IS NOT NULL
AND D.N IS NOT NULL)
UNION ALL
#SECONDA GENERAZIONE
(SELECT CC.PARENT AS ID, DD.N AS N
FROM
(SELECT AA.ID AS ID, BB.PARENT AS PARENT
FROM CATEGORIAS AA
LEFT JOIN CATEGORIAS BB
ON AA.PARENT=BB.ID
WHERE BB.PARENT IS NOT NULL) CC
LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.ID, COUNT(*) AS N
FROM CATEGORIAS A
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTOS B
ON A.ID = B.CATEGORIA_ID
WHERE A.ACTIVE IS TRUE AND B.ACTIVE IS TRUE
GROUP BY A.ID) DD
ON CC.ID = DD.ID
WHERE DD.N IS NOT NULL)
UNION ALL
#TERZA GENERAZIONE
(SELECT CCC.PARENT AS ID, DDD.N AS N
FROM
(SELECT AA.ID AS ID, CC.PARENT AS PARENT
FROM CATEGORIAS AA
LEFT JOIN CATEGORIAS BB
ON AA.PARENT=BB.ID
LEFT JOIN CATEGORIAS CC
ON BB.PARENT=CC.ID
WHERE CC.PARENT IS NOT NULL) CCC
LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.ID, COUNT(*) AS N
FROM CATEGORIAS A
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTOS B
ON A.ID = B.CATEGORIA_ID
WHERE A.ACTIVE IS TRUE AND B.ACTIVE IS TRUE
GROUP BY A.ID) DDD
ON CCC.ID = DDD.ID
AND DDD.N IS NOT NULL)) TOT
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: I've tried and it works but now the productos column is returning always 0

Comment: if you give me the structures of tables and some data I will try to help you

Comment: I've addet them to the question

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong: in categorias there are also pos and active fields (I set them respectively to 1 and TRUE for my test) and in productos you miss active (I set it to TRUE in every row). Here is the insert that I used on productos: INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (1,'A','A','A',1.5,1,1,TRUE), (2,'B','B','B',2.5,1,1,TRUE), (3,'C','C','C',2.5,2,1,TRUE), (6,'H','H','H',2.5,3,1,TRUE), (4,'D','D','D',8.5,4,1,TRUE), (7,'G','G','G',2.6,3,4,TRUE), (5,'E','E','E',0.5,5,3,TRUE), (8,'F','F','F',2.2,3,1,TRUE);

Comment: maybe it doesn't make sense, but it seems to work. I mean, with these data the productos column contains 1 in everyrow. If it's not good give me some data to use in products and, if possible, even the result that you expect.

Comment: [Archivo.zip](http://stylecre.es/sushiber/archivo.zip) Here are my two tables. I want the number of products that have each category including the products in child categories. If I do it with the first sql individuali for example for id = 11 I get 94 in productos column. or for id=5 I get 85 in productos column.

Comment: I edited the answer, I hope it works. It's not as elegant as yours, but if you know how deep are subcategories you can follow a way like this.